# how to bake texture from materials correctly?

Tags: python, materials, texture-baking

What is wrong with me?

Plane with materials on the left and texture on the right

You can answer in python

[image]

Comment: Do you just need to bake a plane? If so, why? Do you want to create a setup where you can render an image without any changes as a basis for your project (and then add some stuff), or do you you want to bake an actual mesh (something more complex than a plane), but the plane is just for a simple test?

Comment: @Markus von Broady - I want to use a texture from materials

Comment: @Markus von Broady - yes it is with uv grid(but I think it doesn't matter)